# Javascript dynamic content loading without using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an array list of news articles to display at the front end. But i only want to display the first 5 on load. When user scrolls to almost near the end of the div (instead of bottom end as i have a default footer), then it will populate another 5 more so on and so forth. 
I am using angularjs limitTo to control how many new articles to display.

With the codes i have, when scroll to the end of the div, it will load a lot of new articles (more than 5) when i scroll and it does not work well in mobile view. Anyone can teach me how to make the content load as i scroll like YouTube page except not scrolling all the way to the end with an array list of data.

```html
<div ng-repeat="news in ctrl.newsList | limitTo:ctrl.displayLimit">
```

```js
var ctrl.displayLimit = 5;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 300) {
    if (ctrl.newsList.length > ctrl.displayLimit) {
      ctrl.displayLimit = ctrl.displayLimit + 5;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The Youtube example you cite is using AJAX. If you do not wish to use AJAX then you will need to include *every* item in to the DOM when the page loads, then dynamically hide and show them. It's certainly possible, but it may not be the best approach depending on how many items there are.

Comment: Small correction to @RoryMcCrossan you don't have to load everything into the dom, you just have to load all entries without a limit and then the displayLimit increment should actually work.

Comment: I think the underlying issue is more that the displayLimit gets incremented far too many times before the new content is actually rendered and thus the window height hasn't changed yet. A working implementation could wait until the scroll event hasn't been triggered for a specified amount of time (like 100-500ms) and only then increment the displayLimit

Comment: sorry maybe to clarify, i want to make it load 5 each time, then reach to the bottom of the div then load another 5. with my codes, i think this line ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 300) will make my news article keep +5 +5 as i scroll.

Comment: @JensV yup that was my problem...

Comment: sorry. im unfamiliar with ajax and dont really how it really works. if my ctrl.newsList is actually result concat from 3 different list. 2 from different rest API and 1 from external API concat tgt. can i still use ajax for this?